# Git: Forget about upstream repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working with a small team on a private repo. At first I thought that we should follow a fork and merge workflow, so I started a 'project-official' repository and forked it into my own 'project' repo. No one else has used the official repo yet, and I have realized that forking and merging is not optimal for this project. How can I disconnect the 'project' repo from the 'project-official' repo before deleting 'project-official'? It's redundant now.

The reason I don't want to fork and merge is because the wiki is not forked as part of the project on Bitbucket, and because we only want one central issue tracker. I would prefer to make 'task' branches and merge them as they are completed.

**update**

To clean up the .git/config file, I will remove `[remote "upstream"]`, right? I am keeping the fork, not the original repo. No one but me has touched either repo.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"] ### This has the URL of the repo I am keeping.
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@bitbucket.org:d4goxn/project.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "upstream"] ### This has the URL of the repo that I have deleted.
    url = git@bitbucket.org:d4goxn/project-official.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forking of the repo, creates a clone in BitBucket.  The only thing that you want to make sure is that there are no changes in the 'project-official' repo that you want in 'project'.  Beyond that just deleting the 'project-official' repo is all that you should need to do.

Comment: Well that was easy! I'm glad Bitbucket reminded me to grab a copy of the wiki first though. Accepting in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you should simply do:

$git push origin :master

Or you can:

vi /.git
and remove the setion titled "[remote "origin]". This section will continue down to the next bracketed label.

It will consist of a few lines similar to:

```
url = ssh://server/dir/git_repo.git fetch =
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: It looks like I should remove the `[remote "upstream"]` section in `.git/config`. `[remote "origin"]` points to the repo that I am keeping.

Comment: The section that is labeled : "[branch "master]" is the repo that will be the one that you are keeping.  That is if I understand your question correctly.   You might want to checkout one of the graphical git tools that are out there.  There are many good ones.  I use http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/.

Comment: if you can copy your <project_dir>/.git/config file to the question, we can get a better idea.